# What is wrong with my android code?

Tags: android, linkify

```
public class WypadekInformacjeActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv1;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wypadek);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
//        webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        webView.setBackgroundColor(0);
        LoadText lt = new LoadText();
        String html = lt.load(R.raw.wypadek, this);

        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}?");

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv1.setAutoLinkMask(0);
//        Linkify.addLinks(tv1, pattern, "tel: ");
//        tv1.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.PHONE_NUMBERS);
    }
}
```

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(28184): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

...

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.swubezpieczenia.WypadekInformacjeActivity.onCreate(WypadekInformacjeActivity.java:29)

It happens when when I try to setAutoLinkMask(0). This is line 29: "tv1.setAutoLinkMask(0);". When I comment this line there is no exception.

Comment: DOes textView1 belong to wypadek?

Comment: Is R.id.textView1 the correct id for the text view?

Comment: textView1 didn't belong to wypadek. You solved it, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your text view does not exist. 
try wrapping line 29 with an 'if' statement such as this:

```
if(tv1 != null){
   //original line 29 goes here
}
```

and run it again. The exception shouldn't happen this time. If it indeed does not happen,
I think your best bet would be to recheck the name of your text view, make sure it exits in the same layout xml you are sending to setContentView().

Answer (score -1):

You are referring to an undeterminated index "0", use [**Linkify**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html#ALL) to refer to a valid index

**Example:**

```
tv1.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.ALL);
```

Comment: Using 0 would not cause a NullPointerException. Perhaps a InvalidInputException or such.

Comment: True. My wrong there, and saw he already have code commented with linkify

Comment: Anyway your info is good and important. I which they used ENUM instead of ints for such things.